# Can somebody please explain IOS line authentication?

Tags: cisco, ios

I'm trying to understand a config on one of our Cisco routers (teaching myself iOS) and have run into a problem with one line.

Can somebody please explain the "line enable" piece of the command below and check the rest of my information to ensure it is correct?

---

```
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local line enable
---
# Creates an authentication list that specifies the types of authentication methods allowed.

# aaa authentication login = command to authenticate users who want exec (enable) access into the access server (tty, vty, console, and aux).
## default = the named list is the the default one (in this case the default one is default)

# There are three authentication methods:
## TACACS+
## local
## line

# All users are authenticated using the tacacs+ server (the first method). If the TACACS+ server doesn't respond, then the router's local database is used (the second method). The local authentication, define the username and password::
## username xxx password yyy

# Because we are using the list default in the aaa authentication login command, login authentication is automatically applied for all login connections (such as tty, vty, console, and aux).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`line` and `enable` are additional methods of authentication that will be attempted after failure of the previous methods in the list.

`line` authentication uses a password that's defined in your `line` configs, so it can vary based on your connection method.  `enable` authentication simply uses the `enable` password defined in the `enable password` command.

Here's a reference of the methods available for the authentication list:

```
(config)#aaa authentication login default ?
  cache        Use Cached-group
  enable       Use enable password for authentication.
  group        Use Server-group
  krb5         Use Kerberos 5 authentication.
  krb5-telnet  Allow logins only if already authenticated via Kerberos V
               Telnet.
  line         Use line password for authentication.
  local        Use local username authentication.
  local-case   Use case-sensitive local username authentication.
  none         NO authentication.
```